# Fixed header bug in IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, position

I'm creating a website with a fixed header. The following code works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but IE9 (and probably earlier versions) ignores the `margin-top` of the `.container`, making it appear behind the `.header` (= sticked to the top of the page).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .header {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            background: transparent;
            border: 5px solid green;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .content {
            height: 200px;
            width: 100%;
            background: orange;
            margin-top: 110px; /* IE ignores this */
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">Header</div>

        <div class="content">Content.</div>
    </body>
<html>
```

Oddly enough, if I switch the header and content...

```
    <body>
        <div class="content">Content.</div>

        <div class="header">Header</div>
    </body>
```

... IE9 renders the page correctly (as do other browsers).

I would like to avoid this, as it breaks the logical order of the document. Any suggestions?

Comment: use padding in stead of margin. Always use padding when you can, IE is very bad with margins in my experience

Comment: No way. I tested in IE9 (9.0.8112.1621), works fine

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Odd, the error occurs on my IE9 (9.0.8112.16421) on Windows 7. I will use padding to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

simply give float:left; to class content.

```
    .content {height:200px;width:100%;background:orange;margin-top:110px;
float:left;}
```

definitely it will works and never forget to give charset declaration for ie in header, its simply likes below.

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```